# Test failure because model couldn't be imported

Tags: django, python-3.x

Application I am working on is proprietary and thus I will try to provide as much information as possible.

When running `python manage.py test`, which runs all the tests, only one application among many others fails. Too many hours have been burned on this.

The output is:

> ImportError: Failed to import test module: app.aom.apps.forum.tests

after this, tracing is listed and then one line which says that the problem occurs when importing models into tests.py file, that is:

```
from .models import ForumSectionGroup, ForumSection, ForumThread, ForumPost
```

and the last line of the output is:

> RuntimeError: Model class app.aom.apps.forum.models.ForumSectionGroup doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

I have Googled and researched what could cause this problem, and the conclusion: either I am importing module before application is loaded or I don't have the application listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. But none of these seems to be the problem. Maybe testing mechanism somehow skips few steps and renders the model unloaded before importing it.

Explicitly assigning `app_label` as part of `class Meta` in the model results in conflict, because the model ends up registered twice, when I force it. I was driven to this conclusion by looking at the code at line 111, https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py

Comment: Are you able to show us your `settings.py` file?  It sounds like it wasn't added under `INSTALLED_APPS` sections in there.

Comment: I said that it is added under it. Here is the code:
`LOCAL_APPS = ('aom.apps.forum',)`

`INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS`

Of course, `LOCAL_APPS` contains a lot more.

Comment: Ok.  Just to cover all the bases you have your `__init__.py` files in all the correct places too?

Comment: Yes, they are there. The entire application runs fine, just testing fails on that particular module.

Comment: The structure is not standard, as you can see in the tutorials. Maybe that is the problem. A brief hierarchy is

projectname
--> app
----> manage.py
----> aom
------> apps
--------> forum
--> docs
....

You can deduce this from `app.aom.apps.forum.models.ForumSectionGroup`

Comment: Having a nonstandard structure could certainly be a cause of the problem.  I know that Django apps can be rather finicky about having certain files in certain places.

Comment: A new clue. Path of the model `app.aom.apps.forum.models.ForumSectionGroup` is not entirely correct. It should start at `aom`. File `manage.py` is contained IN `app`, everything should start at `aom`. Resolving why that directory is present there could help, if not even solve this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. For me what fixed it was changing
`from .models import Model1, Model2`
to
`from app.models import Model1, Model2`

The `from .model import` syntax works fine in view.py, etc. but in the tests it was not working. This only seems to be the case when using a non-standard structure as pointed out in a comment above.

In my specific case I was using Django 1.11.